# How to check if nested stored procedure was executed in tsqlt

Tags: sql-server, tsqlt

I have stored procedure which conditionally execute nested stored procedure.

In unit test, I need to check if this nested stored procedure was executed.

I tried `tSQLt.SpyProcedure`, but it doesnt seems to work the way i want.

**content of my unit test**

```
-- Assembly
exec tSQLt.SpyProcedure 'procedureName', 'raiserror(''procedureName was fired'',16,1)'

-- Assert
exec tSQLt.ExpectException 'procedureName was fired'

-- Action
exec masterProcedureName -- triggers procedureName
```

but `tsqlt.run 'unitestName'` returns

> failed: (Failure) Expected an error to be raised.

Do you have any idea ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While, as you mentioned, your approach works, I suggest you use the `..._spyprocedurelog` table instead. It’ll allow you to catch multiple executions as well as the parameters passed each time. And if you at some point add error handling to the outer procedure, this will still work.

Check out the example in the [SpyProcedure documentation](https://tsqlt.org/user-guide/isolating-dependencies/spyprocedure/).

Comment: Thank you i didnt know about `spyprocedurelog` table.

Answer (score 0):

My apologies, following code does work i had mistake somewhere else.